# WiFi two factor authentication with certificate

Tags: authentication, certificate, wifi

I'm researching how to most securely implement a WiFi network in a professional environment.  What I have so far is to utilize WPA2-Enterprise PEAP with EAP-TLS.  There are unique certificates deployed in the environment and of course users have their personal credentials.

My question is this:  Is there a way to implement two factor authentication for a WiFi network utilizing UID/Passwords and certificates please?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you means two different authentication method? e.g: WPA2-Personal and WPA2-Enterprize . Do you want to use programming to implement this or just configure a Access Point to achieve it?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  To clarify, I want to have a user provide credentials as well as their certificate to be validated by the AP (via RADIUS backend) utilizing WPA2-Ent.  When a user wants to join a WiFi network, they would provide both credentials and their unique certificate to the AP.  Ideally I'd like an AP to do this.